# How to get a high resolution app icon for any application on a Mac?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsworkspace

Apple documentation specifies that [NSWorkspace icon(forFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528158-icon) returns a 32x32 icon, but I'm not sure how to specify a different size.

This is a sample SwiftUI code I'm using to display the icon for XCode:

```swift
Image(
  nsImage: NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: "/Applications/XCode.app/")
).renderingMode(.original)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way I found is to use [`bestRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519961-bestrepresentation). You should pass in the dimensions you want the image to be in (e.g. 1024x1024), and it will find you the best representation there is for that size.

```
if let rep = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: "/Applications/XCode.app/")
    .bestRepresentation(for: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 1024), context: nil, hints: nil) {

}
```

Then you can just `draw` the `NSImageRep`, or create an `NSImage` using it:

```
let image = NSImage(size: rep.size)
image.addRepresentation(rep)
```